recommended c++ structure to frequently query for True / False statuses out of a population of a few thousand members
Is there a canonically "best" (most efficient) C++ structure to fill with a few thousand members in, say, ~20 groups, to then frequently query if a given member is already taken? For instance, for each group, the following would work:

map<int,bool> is_taken would work; updated with is_taken[member]=True and quearied with if(is_taken[member]) would work
set<int> is_taken initiated with no members, updated with is_taken.insert(member) and quearied with is_taken.find(member)!=is_taken.end()

I know in the end, I will just have to profile the results, but is there a good rule of thumb for standard library (or perhaps boost library) solution? The members are just a 64 bit integers.
The background is code clustering hits in a physics experiment into ionization tracks. There are typically a few thousand hits to cluster, each indexed by an integer code indicating their location. The algorithm needs to frequently query the hits if they are already used.

If you only fill it once, sorted std::vector<int> would be best. If you need to modify it, it depends on how often you would modify it. std::map is a safe and well-round option. Though for few thousand members, the whole question may be irrelevant unless you do the operations in tight loop.

Also consider std::unordered_set.

Are the member ints randomly distributed in a range, or are they always 0-~1000?  std::bitset or std::vector<bool> might be optimal here.

@Mooing Duck: the distribution of the ints are tied to a mapping to physical locations in the physics experiment. The amount of signal (number of hits) varied widely depending on conditions of the particles colliding. So there will definitely be a distribution to the pattern of which ints are taken, but it would take serious profiling to see what they are.

Both std::map and std::set are inappropriate data structures if you care about speed. That's because they are are ordered containers and are typically implemented as a binary tree. Not only does that mean lookups take multiple traversals, but also means expensive addition or deletion, and possible cache performance issues due to small dynamic allocations. unordered_set is better, but still allocates every data value. The Boost.Intrusive containers may be more appropriate if you can measure a real performance issue here.

Boost.intrusive is generally good advice but... not for ints.  Rereading the description, I think the best easy option is a B-tree (NOT A BINARY TREE), and the best best option would be a hashset/unordered_set that doesn't do per-node allocations.

I think the problem description isn't nearly good enough, but in the off-chance that the "groups" (?) are somewhat related maybe Boost Interval Container (interval_set/interval_map) can give some inspiration. If so, ... consider whether a spatial index is relevant.

As mentioned, likely not the solution, but the std set containers have .contains() since C++20, so no need to do find!=end
